# Issues with Runner using Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm having a problem I have Flutter app which I'm configuring it to be able to be use in iOS the problem is that when I run it in Xcode it runs but leave the initial page totally blank.

Like this:

[image: Blank Phone]

When I check the Xcode I see this:

It opens AppDelegate.swift

and I see this code:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

And get this exception:

```
Exception   NSException *   "`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/."    0x000060000351d380
```

But in my Visual Studio Code where I did the app I put inside the Runner Folder the GoogleServices-Info.plist file:

[image: Google Service plist]

I'm not sure if this is affection but these are the Extentions been use on my project from pub.dev:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^5.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  photo_view: ^0.11.1
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.1
  firebase_core: ^1.1.1
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.4
  image_picker: ^0.7.5
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.6
  random_string: ^2.1.0
  algolia: ^1.0.1
  custom_switch: ^0.0.1
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^4.0.5955
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^2.0.4
  share: ^2.0.2
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  http: ^0.13.3
```

Which I know require extra configuration only these ones:

```
url_launcher
  image_picker
  google_sign_in
  firebase_dynamic_links
  flutter_facebook_login
```

In any case this is my info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>RoofDeck</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>property1</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow Permission to use the Image Gallery</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow Permission to use the Camera</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow Permission to use the Microphone</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>RoofDeck requires access to the photo library.</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>RoofDeck requires access to the microphone.</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>RoofDeck requires access to the camera.</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>http</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <!-- TODO Replace this value: -->
            <!-- Copied from GoogleService-Info.plist key REVERSED_CLIENT_ID -->
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.0000000000-00000000000000000</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <!--
              Replace "000000000000" with your Facebook App ID here.
              **NOTE**: The scheme needs to start with `fb` and then your ID.
            -->
            <string>fb000000000000/string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

<key>FacebookAppID</key>

<!-- Replace "000000000000" with your Facebook App ID here. -->
<string>000000000000</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>

<!-- Replace "YOUR_APP_NAME" with your Facebook App name. -->
<string>RoofDeck</string>

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

FYI I have the correct Facebook App id on the Strings just for safety I don't added here also the proper Google Reversed Client Id as well.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're following the [Algolia Flutter documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/getting-started/how-to/flutter/ios/) to get set up. I also ran into issues following their docs. In the end, I ended up using the unofficial [Algolia package](https://pub.dev/packages/algolia) that made the setup much easier, and with no issues.